# How to check for sideways car in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to check for sideways car in Unity? That means, can anyone gimme a C# script to check if my car is sideways fallen to the ground, then reset it straight up. My car, using UNity Physics works all right. But when it turns sideways and falls to the ground, I am not able to reset it. I tried to use quaternion but it didn't work. I don't know how to make a C# script to implement that. My script name is `CarSideways` and the car is still a cube.

This is my script to move the car:

```
     private void Update() {
         Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
             rb.AddForce(Vector3.left);
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
             rb.AddForce(Vector3.right);
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
             rb.AddForce(Vector3.up);
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
             rb.AddForce(Vector3.down);
 
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick SUGGESTION: In start store the rotation of the car in a Vector3 variable. After the car is flipped sideways, set the rotation again to the stored value.

```
public class CarController : MonoBehavior
{
// adjust the angles as per your needs
public float maxLeftAngle = 315f;
public float maxRightAngle = 45f;

void Update()
{
if ((transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < maxLeftAngle) || (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > maxRightAngle))
{
Debug.Log("The car is turned sideways");
// reset the rotation
}
}
}
```